# Replace numbers between parts of string using regex

Tags: python, regex

I want to replace numbers between some part of string

for eg :.

```
f = "abc 123 def 23435 kill x22 y2986"
```

I want to replace all umber between `def` and `y` with `#`

Tried using the following expression , it didnt work

```
exp = re.sub(r"(?<=def)\d+(?=y)", "#", f)
```

Expected output :

```
abc 123 def ##### kill x## y2986
```

Comment: That regex matches "def, followed immediately by a digit sequence, followed immediately by a y". Your string has things other than digit sequences between "def" and "y", so it doesn't match.

Comment: So what is the way to do it

Comment: Looping is one.

Comment: But isnt there any way that regex can be applied between some words

Comment: What luck! @JitendraAswani, check out ritesht93's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48345344/1116098).

Comment: I don't know a lot of the formal theory, but I suspect that detecting patterns of text in specific contexts, such as "between this token and that other token", is approaching the limit of what ordinary regex can do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I think at first glance it seems it is difficult to do it with regex but there is a way to do it by applying regex in multiple levels (in this case 2 levels). Here is an example:

```
>>> f = "abc 123 def 23435 kill x22 y2986" 
>>> import re
>>> exp = re.sub(r"(?<=def)(.*)(?=y)", lambda x:re.sub(r"\d", '#', x.group()), f)
>>> exp
'abc 123 def ##### kill x## y2986'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

in the general case it is not possible without a variable length lookbehind, however in that particular case it can be done with a positive and a negative lookahead however it may replace digit if there is another `y` after last `y` :

```
\d(?!.*def[^y]*y)(?=[^y]*y)
```

matches a digit

- which is not followed by `def[^y]*y` : digit is not before `def..y`
- and is followed by `[^y]*y` : digit is before `..y`

[check here regex101](https://regex101.com/r/1zVuYs/1/)

Comment: reread my answer ;), it is explained it works only for the case in the question